# What is the purpose of {" "} in react?

Tags: reactjs

I can't search on the web the purpose of {" "} in react? What does this do?

```
<p> Hello I a'm a {" "} programmer </p>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is useful if you want to insert variable's value
Example:

```
const name = "Messi"
<p>Hello, my name is {name}</p>
```

In your case, a whitespace will be inserted

Answer (score -1):

Curly braces { } are special syntax in JSX. It is used to evaluate a JavaScript expression during compilation. A JavaScript expression can be a variable, function, an object, or any code that resolves into a value.

```
const isProgrammer  = true;
<p> Hello I am a {isProgrammer ? "programmer" : "non-propgrammer"} </p>
```

In you case, it will executed and return a white space. There are have 3 white space but it will only show 1 because spaces are compacted in HTML.

`<p> Hello I am a {" "} programmer </p>` the same with `<p> Hello I am a{" "}programmer </p>`